# how to read external app.config as xml file in winforms?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

How to read `app.config` file as normal xml and read the connectionString Key/value

from configuration ->connectionStrings node

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="appConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=DEV6-PC;Initial Catalog=ireg.est;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa@123" providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  <configuration>
```

Comment: I want to read external app.config file as normal xml file

Comment: **SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["appConnStr"].ToString());** is this what you have expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var element = XDocument.Load("filepath")
                       .Descendants("connectionStrings")
                       .FirstOrDefault();
var connStrings = new Dictionary<string,string>();
if(element != null)
{
   foreach(var item in element.Elements("add"))
   {
      var name = (string)item.Attribute("name");
      var connString = (string)item.Attribute("connectionString");
      connStrings.Add(name,connString);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: here im reading the file as an xml document and retrieving the connection string attribute.

```
string connString=null;
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.load("yourconfigfielpath"); // add your file path here.
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/xml/configuration/connectionstrings");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
         connString=node["add"].GetAttribute("connectionString");
}
```

hope this helps.